# Facebook API PHP - Getting number of likes of a posted video

Tags: php, facebook, api

I want to get number of likes of a video, posted on a facebook page in video section...

I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

If I pass this,

```
$response=$facebook->api("/PAGE ID/videos");
```

I'm getting all posted videos of my PAGE. But I can't get the number of people who like the video. I'm sure more number of people is liking the video.

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook->api_client->fql_query('SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="122706168308"');
```